# Debian detects printer family, but no double sided printing; colors are inaccurate

Tags: debian, drivers, colors, printing, canon

On Debian 9.8 I use a [Canon PIXMA MG2555](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2555s.html) printer.

1) A global driver for PIXMA MG2500 series printers has been installed automatically by GNOME. It seems that no more accurate driver exists, and I was not invited to do any additional settings.

However, this driver doesn't detect that my printer can work both sides of paper, and the colors printed are wrong. Blue for example, is very dark (nearly black) when it shall be lively.

Openoffice and Libreoffice can print titles and subtitles with wrong colors, but images will look nearly ok, even if not absolutely good.

Before Debian, I was on Windows 7 and the Windows 7 drivers worked correctly.

2) Are you aware that such problems can happen?
3) Is there thing that could be wrong in other parts of my operation system configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution for double-sided pages.

But colors were wrong due to a bad default settings I correct through *CUPS* (http://localhost:631) : I sat Color Model from `RGB` to `CMY`.

Answer (score 2):

1) GNOME did the best it could when the manufacturer withdraws support.

2) We are aware that imperfect results may follow when there is no driver for a specific piece of hardware.
3) If you have other unsupported hardware, there may be other errors in configuration.

You may wish to consider acquiring a printer where the manufacturer supports Linux. "Unfortunately your device is no longer supported under the selected operating system" sayeth Canon at t[heir drivers page](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg2555s.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit)).